# Too Many Arguments For Format String Error (Code in **)

Tags: python

As you can see Im trying to make Pong, The problem being the Player A or "nameA" Score Stays as "{}" Any fix? If theres anyone that knows what exactly is the problem and how I can avoid it in the future please let me know. The code in between the **"code"** is what needs fixing.

```
import turtle
nameA = input("Player A Enter Your Name!")
nameB = input("Player B Enter Your Name!")

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write(nameA + ": 0 " + nameB + ": 0 ", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

# Main game loop
while True:
wn.update()

#Move the ball
ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

#Border checking
if ball.ycor() > 290:
    ball.sety(290)
    ball.dy *= -1

if ball.ycor() < -280:
    ball.sety(-280)
    ball.dy *= -1

if ball.xcor() > 380:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1
    score_b += 1
    pen.clear()
    **pen.write(nameA +": {} " + nameB+": {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))**

if ball.xcor() < -390:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1
    score_a += 1
    pen.clear()
    **pen.write(nameA +": {} " + nameB+": {}".format(score_a, score_b), align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))**

    # Paddle and ball collisions
if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -50):
    ball.setx(340)
    ball.dx *= -1
if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -50):
    ball.setx(-340)
    ball.dx *= -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression in question is

```
": {}".format(score_a, score_b)
```

You have a string with only one format slot, but you're trying to force two variables into it.

Function call binds more tightly than string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `f'` strings. like this: `f'{nameA} : {score_a} {nameB}: {score_b}'`

Like this:

```
import turtle
nameA = input("Player A Enter Your Name!")
nameB = input("Player B Enter Your Name!")

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write(nameA + ": 0 " + nameB + ": 0 ", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

#Move the ball
ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

#Border checking
if ball.ycor() > 290:
    ball.sety(290)
    ball.dy *= -1

if ball.ycor() < -280:
    ball.sety(-280)
    ball.dy *= -1

if ball.xcor() > 380:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1
    score_b += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f'{nameA} : {} {score_a} {nameB} : {score_b}', align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

if ball.xcor() < -390:
    ball.goto(0, 0)
    ball.dx *= -1
    score_a += 1
    pen.clear()
    pen.write(f'{nameA} : {score_a} {nameB} : {score_b}', align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

    # Paddle and ball collisions
if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_b.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_b.ycor() -50):
    ball.setx(340)
    ball.dx *= -1
if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < paddle_a.ycor() + 50 and ball.ycor() > paddle_a.ycor() -50):
    ball.setx(-340)
    ball.dx *= -1
```